# Shimura reciprocity law

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have spent quite some time understanding class fields generated by Kummer extensions and class fields generated by modular forms. Now, I am turning the notch of sophistication a bit to study class fields generated by Shimura reciprocity law. Where I can obtain a good motivation to  Shimura reciprocity and obtain some explicit calculation of class fields by Shimura's method. Please guide on some lucid sources which explain these objects.

Comment: In the second edition of "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$", David Cox added a section on Shimura reciprocity which does contain some explicit examples and some reproofs of earlier results in his book. I would recommend this source.

Comment: I have the first edition of David Cox's book. If the second edition contains what I want, then my purpose is served. Thanks a lot,sir !